# jquery datatable plugin: i want to customize jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery datatable ([example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)).
I want these changes:

1. I want to change the options of show entries dropdown.
2. I want to use show entries, search and paging footer in some different div (other than the div in which my table reside). Want to keep them apart as these are always keep sticking to the table.
3. When I use paging the table shoud not move. It shoud be fix in boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [examples](http://www.datatables.net/examples/) and [options reference](http://www.datatables.net/ref) you will surely find your answers. [This](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html), [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) and [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html) may help you with point 2.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the options of show entries dropdown.

Use the [`aLengthMenu`](http://datatables.net/ref#aLengthMenu) parameter:

```
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
```

> I want to use show entries, search and paging footer in some different
>   div (other than the div in which my table reside). Want to keep them
>   apart as these are always keep sticking to the table.

Use the [`sDom`](http://datatables.net/ref#sDom) parameter. You can inject `div`s and customize existing ones with custom classes.

> When I use paging the table shoud not move. It shoud be fix in
>   boundaries.

Add fixed width and height to your `table`.